# Problem related to OLS estimators

Tags: self-study, least-squares, regression-coefficients, matrix

The problem is:

> Suppose we fit a model Y = X<sub>A</sub> β<sub>A</sub> +  ε. However, the true model is Y = X<sub>A</sub> β<sub>A</sub> + X<sub>B</sub> β<sub>B</sub> +  ε. A is k<sub>A</sub> x 1 and B is k<sub>B</sub> x 1. Show that the OLS estimates of β<sub>A</sub> will still be equal if X<sup>T</sup><sub>A</sub>X<sub>B</sub> = 0.

My attempt at a solution:

Under OLS, the estimate of β is (X<sup>T</sup>X)<sup>-1</sup>X<sup>T</sup>Y. So I was thinking for the first model, we just have X = X<sub>A</sub>, but in the second model, we have X = X<sub>A</sub> + X<sub>B</sub>. So I was trying to expand (X<sup>T</sup>X)<sup>-1</sup>X<sup>T</sup>Y but subbing in the previous values for X, and then seeing if anything stood out, but I wasn't having any luck.

Any help or tips would be appreciated

Comment: Are $k_A$ & $k_B$ supposed to be equal? It seems like that should be mentioned.

Answer (score 4):

In the second model $X=[X_A,X_B]$, not $X=X_A+X_B$. This is where the confusion comes in. Substitute the correct matrix into the $X^TX$ and note that the proposed condition makes the matrix diagonal like. Think what this implies. Or alternatively use [Frisch–Waugh–Lovell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frisch%E2%80%93Waugh%E2%80%93Lovell_theorem) theorem.